# MP4Box - create single MPD files with multiple videos

Tags: video, video-streaming, mpeg-dash, mp4box, adaptive-bitrate

I am working on a problem where I have to play multiple videos, one after another using DASH. I do not want them to be combined into one MP4. Each video (each represenatation) has its own segment file (single segment). Then I use MP4Box to create a single mpd file with multiple periods so that video1 is in Period 1 and video2 is in Period 2, hoping that they would run one after another.
The MP4Box command is as follows

```
MP4Box -dash 10000 -profile onDemand -single-file video1_320_24.mp4#video:period=1 video1_480_24.mp4#video:period=1 video1_480_24.mp4#audio:period=1 video2_320_24.mp4#video:period=2 video2_480_24.mp4#video:period=2 video2_480_24.mp4#audio:period=2
```

This generates a single mod file with 2 periods. But when I run the video using SHAKA player https://shaka-player-demo.appspot.com/demo/#lang=en-GB, the video hangs while the switch happens from one period to another.

Could somebody please help me what am I doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: did you end up resolving this? I need to do a similar thing - dynamically create mpd from user selected multiples.

Comment: No, the video still hangs when transitioning from one video to another.

Comment: I got it to work for my purposes (I use a xml2js parser and merge X mpds together), you need to adjust the start attribute for the periods and the mediaPresentationDuration of the mpd. Oh and adjust paths

Comment: Could  you please post your solution here with some example.

Comment: It is not a trivial task but is possible. Cant post examples and in either case it will be dependant on the format of you streams. But I did write about my process where I am successfully generating dynamic documentaries from user selected clips by merging Dash and hls streams https://medium.com/@rburnie/merging-video-stream-data-54442cc6ea59